# Set maximumPoolSize and minimumIdle based on processor and memory server

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jvm

i have a 4 JVM applications running into 4 servers. (one instance/server)

My Oracle DB opens only for 300 process (max).

the default pool connection size is 10 (since i didn't changed before);
du to many requests to my Oracle DB, i got exceptions like

**"Unable to aquire JDBC connection**"

**HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms**

**IO Error: Got minus one from a read call**

I could see this notice but i couldn't find the best configuration for my params :
**Thread pools need to be sized with the total number of hardware processor cores in mind**

My servers are based on this configuration (same configuration *4) :

memoire size : **grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo**  **24Go**

processor number : **cat /proc/cpuinfo   6**

i want to increase those two params in my Spring boot application to avoid exceptions and do not explose the memory.

```
# HikariCP settings
     spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle= **
     spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize= **
```

what will be those params ?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the maximumPoolSize? You can put more connections than cores since the number of threads is not limited by the number of cores.

Comment: Number of database connections has nothing to do with cores/threads. You need to increase your database connection pool size according to your load.

Comment: i just edit my questiion, hope its clear
@Gas the DB connection pool is 300 process

Comment: 300 processes at the same time? if so, why not increasing the Hikari connection pool to 300?